# Windows 10 Secondary Drive will not power down after X amount of minutes (querying full size volume information issue)

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

**Problem:**
I have a secondary hard drive on my pc for storing games etc, I want this to shut down when not in use to reduce noise. I have tried setting the hard drive timeoff to 6 minutes in power options. This does not work. I know the disk is not faulty as the same setting worked in windows 7, and still currently does.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Disabled Search Indexing for that drive
- Disabled automatic defrag and optimisation for that drive
- *Analysed processes with process monitor, and a filter to only look for activity on the drive. Every 10 minutes explorer.exe is creating
  a file, then "querying full size volume information" then closing the
  file.*
- I do not have Intel RST drivers installed (this is supposedly a known
  bug)

Any help much appreciated, I am stumped.

**EDIT: For anyone who stumbles upon this thread with a similar issue at a later date, I narrowed it down to speedfan. Specifically, you need to disable temperature monitoring for the hard drive to allow it to spool down. To do this, in speedfan go to configure> temperatures> un-tick the text box next to the HDD you want to spool down.**

Comment: My solution was getting an SSD for the secondary drive, so there's nothing moving to make a noise. It *might* be a mitigating option for you.

Comment: I have considered this, but I do like the recoverability of a hard drive if something were to go wrong, and I can't afford a 1TB SSD at the moment.